# Can the Kestrel receive form-data with an endpoint instead of a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel

I want to use asp.net core Kestrel to make a simple server receive picture files from the html clients. I use an endpoint instead of a controller to get the target. Some browser have a size limit of posting the large url encoded string so I have to choose form-data rather than url-encoding. But I cannot receive any form-data in the server-side endpoint method:

client side:

```
    <form id="form" action="/api/do" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </p>
    </form>
```

server side:

```
//register the endpoint
endpoints.MapPost("/api/do", Do);
.
.
.
async Task Do(HttpContext context)
{
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var file = form.Files[0];
    ....
}
```

The length of **form.Files** is always 0.

Must I use a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what's wrong with the codes, I forgot to give a name of the "input element". If there is no name of the input element the browser will not submit it.